# What is a Ruby factory method?

Tags: ruby, factory-pattern, factory-method

I understand that a factory method is a class method that utilises the `self` keyword and instantiates an object of it's own class. I don't understand how this is useful or how it can extend the functionality of `initialize` method.

I'm working on a project creating a command line address book that asks me to use a factory pattern on the Person class so that I can create a Trainee or Instructor (subclasses) with different attributes.

Comment: @JörgWMittag so initialize methods are not constructors? If not then how would you define them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A factory class is a clean way to have a single factory method that produces various kind of objects.
It takes a parameter, a parameter that tells the method which kind of object to create. For example to generate an `Employee` or a `Boss`, depending on the symbol that is passed in:

```
class Person
  def initialize(attributes)
  end
end

class Boss
  def initialize(attributes)
  end
end

class Employee
  def initialize(attributes)
  end
end

class PersonFactory
  TYPES = {
    employee: Employee,
    boss: Boss
  }

  def self.for(type, attributes)
    (TYPES[type] || Person).new(attributes)
  end
end
```

and then:

```
employee = PersonFactory.for(:employee, name: 'Danny')
boss = PersonFactory.for(:boss, name: 'Danny')
person = PersonFactory.for(:foo, name: 'Danny')
```

I also wrote a more detailed blog post about that topic: [The Factory Pattern](http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/the-factory-pattern)

Answer (score 4):

The Factory Method Pattern at least allows you to give an expressive name to what could otherwise be a complicated or opaque constructor.  For instance if you have a constructor that takes a bunch of parameters, it may not be clear why to the caller, having a named Factory method or methods could potentially hide the complexity of the object creation and make your code more expressive of what is actually going on.

So in your case a bad design may be:

`trainee = Person.new true`

or

`instructor = Person.new false`

Where true or false branches to creating an instructor or trainee.

This could be improved by using a Factory method to clarify what is going on:

```
trainee = Person.create_trainee
instructor = Person.create_instructor
```

Comment: Are you saying that the primary purpose of the factory method is not to extend the functionality of the object creation process, but to make your code more less complicated and more readable?

Answer (score 1):

### Why bother with factory methods?

#### (A) **To simplify things**:

- Creating objects can be complicated, and
- you may need to do this multiple times.
- It's hard to remember:

  ```
  driver = Person.new
  engine = Brrrm.new
  engine.turbo_charged = true
  engine.max_rpm = 100000    
  car = Porsche.new
  car.driver = driver
  car.engine = engine
  # ugh - too much work!
  ```

#### Let's simply it to this:

```
  ben = PersonFactory.create(name: "ben")
  car = PorscheFactory.create(driver: ben)
  # two lines, and nothing more

  # and you get the following for free: 
  car.turbo_charged # => true
  car.engine # => brrrm
  car.driver # => ben_koshy
  car.driver.personality # => :excellent_dude

  # you can mix and match default values with options.
  # generally speaking you want to inject as much as you can
  # i.e. inverting dependencies. I make these illustrates to
  # explain a concept, not as an example of great coding.
```

#### (B) **To allow for overridding / stubbing**

If you are writing testable code, you might want to create your own specialised 'crash dummy vehicle' so you can test collisions etc. If you have a factory method / object, then you can do this easily. This is a somewhat adavanced topic - google "creating a seam" or "dependency injection" for more info.